# Loop through JSON object returned from cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, cookies

I know there are a bunch of questions out there regarding this, but I have tried several different proposed solutions and get the same results for each one.

I am storing checkbox values in an array in the format `timeArr = [ event-name-one: 0: 1404915600, 1: 1404917400 ]`. When the array gets updated with a new key/value pair a cookie is updated which stores the array as a JSON object.

I am storing the JSON object in the cookie using `jQuery.cookie('day', JSON.stringify(timeArr), {expires: 7});` which stores the array in the following format (returned from `console.log();`):

`{"event-name-one":{"0":1405346400,"1":1405347600},"event-name-two":{"0":1405357200,"1":1405358400}}`

In this instance `event-name-one` and `event-name-two` are the ID's of the checkboxes. I need to loop through the returned cookie value (JSON object) and check the checkboxes whos ID's are found in the returned cookie.

I have tried a few different loops, i.e. `for(var k in cookieValue){}` and `jQuery.each(jQuery.parseJSON(cookieValue), function(i, v) {});` with no luck.

The `for(var k in cookieValue)` loop returns each letter of the object separately and the `jQuery.each()` loop returns this error: `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '76' in ...`

How can I convert this JSON string back to an array so I can loop through it and get the 'keys'

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle? I couldn't reproduce the problem. I tried `var json = '{"event-name-one":{"0":1405346400,"1":1405347600},"event-name-two":{"0":1405357200,"1":1405358400}}';
jQuery.each(jQuery.parseJSON(json), function(i, v) { console.log(i, v); });`

which logged the following:


`event-name-one Object {0: 1405346400, 1: 1405347600}` and 
`event-name-two Object {0: 1405357200, 1: 1405358400}`

Comment: Unfortunatley I cannot reproduce the issue in a Fiddle. When I put the same code in the fiddle it seems to return properly, but when I have the exact same thing on my server it returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '109' in {"event-name-one":{"0":"1405346400","1":"1405347600"}}` And when I copy & paste your exact JSON string & `$.each()` function above I get an `Unexpected Token` error

Comment: I wouldn't use a cookie for this - I would use localStorage.

Comment: That indicates that whatever you pass into `jQuery.each` isn't an object but a string.

Comment: @Andy I cannot use local storage because this has to be compatible with IE8. I have found my answer and posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery.cookie()` must stringify arrays automatically into JSON objects because in order to get the correct results from the loop I had to use `jQuery.parseJSON()` on the response twice.

Example:

```
var cookieVal = jQuery.cookie('day_planner');
jQuery.each(jQuery.parseJSON(jQuery.parseJSON(cookieVal)), function(i, v) { 
    console.log(i, v); 
});
```

This loop returns `event-name-one Object {0: "1405346400", 1: "1405347600"}`

Comment: The reason why you have to parse twice is *not* the you have multidimensional data. It's because the value is *stringified* twice. It may be that `$.cookie` already converts the value to JSON for you, so just don't call `JSON.stringify(timeArr)`.

Comment: That makes more sense. Updated answer.

Comment: Also, [there is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) ;)

Comment: I suggest you do not strigify when using $.cookie instead of parsing the JSON twice.